# Replacing some string in an SWF/FLASH file using PHP

Tags: php, binary

I have some flash swf files where i hard coded some variables to use with action script like
p='mydomain.com'

I want to replace the value of mydomain.com with a given string using a php script . I know this can be done using Binary operation, but it failed for me . Can anyone help me to find a solution using php 's built in functions only (No third party language) .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have PHP pass variables to the swf file using GET variables.

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/flash_php_mysql.htm

The magic line is this:

```
loadVariables("http://localhost/test.php", this, "GET");
```

**EDIT:**

After considering the options, you may want to store strings that are likely to change in an XML file and read the values at runtime.

http://www.kirupa.com/web/xml/XMLwithFlash3.htm

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/using_xml_as3_pg1.htm

Comment: Hi, Thanks but i know this method works . But in this case someone can edit the test.php and change the varibale value . But i want the varibale to be set in SWF, so no one can change the value, but my php code should do the same . Imagine i have a flash map, when i supply to one client, the swf file should hold a varibale with value as client's website address. If i give the map to another person, i want to change the website address to point to new one . So this should be done using a php script, where i enter the new value and should be replaced on SWF . Thanks

Comment: php will print pass the variable to the swf, in short it means you don't have to edit the swf at all, but it means that you will still need to edit the accompanying php. You could also load it from an XML file.

Comment: Hi,  i understand the solution . But this is specif task. I need the swf content to be replaced . All other solutions , that you explained is correct and i welcomes them. But this is my requirement , to replace some value in SWF file .

Comment: What is wrong with either the XML or PHP providing the data to the swf?

Comment: Hi, i already mentioned, they are good solutions . But my requirement is using only swf file and replace the string dynamically using a script .

Comment: so you need swf and a script, you mentioned php as the script didn't you?

Comment: Hello, i need a PHP  script to replace the text in an swf file . Ex : in swf file there is one value 'mydomain.com' , when i run the php script , value 'mydomain.com' should replaed by 'helloaddress.com', where 'helloaddress.com' is given from the running php script

Comment: That's a very bad way to go about it. It can be done, but it destroys the dynamic aspect and you might as well consider it a find and replace operation. What is wrong with providing an external file (I would go with XML) to store strings? This method is far more flexible and allows you to change the string at any time. If you ran your php script to change the values you would need to know 1. where to look (swfs are compressed I believe) 2. what the old value is and 3. what the new one should be. You run the risk of damaging the contents of the swf or not finding a match at all.

Comment: In short I would not recommend this find and replace using php method. XML is the way to go here I think. Consider that you may have more and more strings later on, such as the name of the client, some background text, along with their domain name you mentioned. Imagine the complexity of the php script after all this time. I can't even begin to think how it would work if the code in the swf were not stored as plain text, and even then, you're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Sorry to all, but you didn't understand my issue well. How many times i repeat the same that , i am in need of find and replace in SWF file. I know XML integration, and using php as config etc etc . I have worked with those stuffs . But this is specific to my requirement . I need exactly the find and replace in SWF. I dont need any other solutions .

Comment: Yes, but I've clearly stated the negative side-effects of that.

Comment: Sorry , i am really tired of explaining again . I need a php script which replaces one value in an swf file with another, which is given by the php script .

Comment: I believe , it is possible by the binary replacement .

Comment: Hmm, if you're adamant I can't really help much further, sorry

Comment: Finally i got some valuable suggestion  for binary replacement ! Thanks for chat friends !

Comment: no probs, glad you found an answer. You may want to post it back here for the benefit of anyone else.